# regularexpression to validate digits only string and length

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to validate a string before I send information to a server with javascript. I want to make sure the string length is 9, and that it contains only digits.

just to mention, this project use jquery mobile controls.

**this is my html controls:**

```
<div data-role="content" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                     <label for="Childid">
                        Child ID</label>
                    <input id="childid" class="textBox" value=""  type="text"/>

                    <label for="ChildfirstName">
                        Child first name</label>
                    <input id="ChildfirstName" class="textBox" value=""  type="text"/>

                     <label for="Childlastname">
                        Child last name</label>
                    <input id="ChildlastName" class="textBox" value=""  type="text"/>

                 <label for="Childmail">
                        Child Mail</label>
                    <input id="ChildMail" class="textBox" value=""  type="text"/>
                </div>

                <label for="Childbudget">
                        Child monthly budget</label>
                    <input id="childmbudget" class="textBox" value=""  type="text"/>
```

**also I wrote this function:**

```
function validateID(id) {
    var re = /\d{9}/;
    return re.test(id);
}
```

**and used it like this:**

```
var id = $('#childid').val();

if( validateID(id) == false )
  $("#fillthefields").popup("open")
```

but it doesn't seem to validate correctly.

and if I'm already asking, how do I validate string to contain only digits and not start with zero digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need regular expressions for this.

You can just use

```
return (id.length === 9 && !isNaN(id));
```

---

Edit: In reply to Samuel's comment

[MDN: isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

[MSDN: isNaN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/66ztdbe6%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

> Return Value
>
> true if the value converted to the Number type is the NaN, otherwise false.

Comment: and if I'm already asking, how do I validate string to contain only digits and not start with zero digit?

Answer (score 0):

use the regex, it will check for a string which contains only 9 digits and does not start with zero.

```
var re = /^[1-9]\d{8}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(validateID(id) == false )
```

to

```
if(validateID(id))
```

and change your regex to

```
var re = /^[1-9]\d{8}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would HTML5 patterns work?

```
 pattern="[0-9]{9}"
```

digit can not start with zero

```
pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8}" title="Please enter 9 digits, can not start with 0"
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/maLE6/
- http://jsfiddle.net/zZyN4/ ( can not start with zero )

Reference

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern

HTML

```
<h1>A Simple HTML5 Form Validation</h1>
<p>Leave the field empty and submit the form to see what happens.</p>

<form>
    <label for="name">* Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" pattern="[0-9]{9}" title="Please enter 9 digits" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<footer>Which browsers support this feature? - <a href=http://caniuse.com/form-validation>Caniuse.com</a></footer>
```